# $X-$ $^T$ $-Y$ $-$ $^S$ $-Z$ is exact then $Z^*$ $-$ $^S*$ $-Y^*$ $-$ $^T*$ $-X^*$ is exact.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, exact-sequence

A sequence $T:X$ $\rightarrow Y$ and $S:Y$ $\rightarrow Z$ is called exact of $RanT=kerS$

Let X,Y and Z be Banach spaces. T is bounded operator from $X$ $\rightarrow$Y

$T$ $\in B(X,Y)$ and $S$ $\in B(Y,Z)$
And suppose S has a closed range. prove that if

$X-$ $^T$ $-Y$$-$ $^S$ $-Z$ is exact then $Z^*$  $-$ $^S*$ $-Y^*$$-$ $^T*$ $-X^*$ is exact.

I have to show that $RanS^*=kerT^*$.  Here * represents the dual space.

I thought of showing two inclusions. That is $RanS^*\subseteq kerT^*$ and $kerT^*\subseteq RanS^*$.

first let $\varphi\in RanS^*$ be a functional then show that $\varphi\in kerT^*$.
I need to show that $\varphi(y^*)=0$ where $y^*\in Y^*$.

Is my approach correct. How I'm going to use the fact that S has a closed range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to show that if we have an exact sequence, then the dual one is exact.Let's look at general case, because it's not difficult, but i will give you a scratch. Let be
$$ ... \longrightarrow L_{k-1} \underset{T_k}{\longrightarrow} L_k \underset{T_{k+1}}{\longrightarrow} L_{k+1}  \longrightarrow ...$$
be an exact sequence, so the dual one
$$ ... \longleftarrow L^*_{k-1} \underset{T*_k}{\longleftarrow} L^*_k \underset{T^*_{k+1}}{\longrightarrow} L^*_{k+1}  \longleftarrow ... $$
The first part $ker T_k^* \subset Im T_{k+1}^*$ is obvious, because $0 = (T_{k+1} T_k)^* = T_k^*T^*_{k+1}$.Let's show other inclusion, let $f$ be an arbitary element of $kerT^*_k$, then $ker T_{k+1} = ImT_k \subset kerf$, then $f$ defines a linear functional F on $ImT_{k+1}$ by formula
$$F(T_{k+1}(x)) = f(x)$$
This functional is continuous, so by Hahn-Banach theorem it can be continued by $F_0 \in L^*_{k+1}$ and $T^*_{k+1}F_0 = f$.
Proof that $F$ is continuous uses the fact that $T_{k+1}$ is bounded

Comment: It is the *Hahn-Banach-theorem*.

Comment: Thank you. First inclusion is clear. But when you are showing the second inclusion, $kerT^*_k \subset ImT^*_k+1$  you have taken an element in $f\in kerT^*$. How does $ImT_k\subset Kerf$.

Comment: If $f \in kerT_k^*$ then $T_k^*(f) = 0 \implies f  \circ T_k = 0$, so we get it.

Comment: Okay. Thank you